# How do I take data from multiple lists that are all inside a single variable in python and find out the mean mode and frequency

Tags: python, list, statistics, var

I'm making a blackjack game that requires me to calculate the scores at the end of multiple blackjack games such as what your cards added up to at the end of the games and find out the mean, mode and frequency. I've gotten the data laid out in a spread sheet but can't figure out how to read and add the score from the separate games since they're all being added together into one variable

```
import csv

with open("nathan_project_data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    a = list(reader)
print(a)
```

with the output being:
[['win', '21'], ['Hit', 'Stand', 'Loss', '17'], ['Hit', 'Stand', 'Loss', '18'], ['Stand', 'Loss', '18'], ['Stand', 'win', '19']]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i75478153/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Woodford My apologies is this way better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index -1 is the index of the last item in a list

```py
import csv

with open("nathan_project_data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    a = list(reader)
print(a)

scores = [] #create list to hold all the scores

for item in a: #Loop through each item (lists) in the list
    scores.append(item[-1]) #Append (add) the last element of each item to 
                            #scores list

print(scores) #prints [21, 17, 18, 18, 19]


#Get Frequency of each score:
frequency = {} #Dictionary to hold frequencies
for score in scores:
   # checking the element in dictionary
   if score in frequency:
      # incrementing the count
      frequency[score] += 1
   else:
      # initializing the count
      frequency[score] = 1

mean = sum(scores)/len(scores)

#Do whatever other calcs you need
```